# Modificar datos en 2 ArrayList al mismo tiempo

Tags: java, arraylist

Mucho gusto, estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto de la universidad en el cual no logro realizar lo siguiente: tengo 2 ArrayList el primero lo llame Usuario donde gestiono toda la información de usuarios; usuario, nombre, apellido, correo, rol; y en el segundo gestiono equipos por lo cual le llame Equipo y en este debo gestionar un nombre para el equipo, id y pasarle el usuario, apellido y nombre del ArrayList Usuario, el problema es que tengo la opción de modificar la información del usuario en un JFrame modificar, ok modifico la información correctamente pero me la modifica solo en el ArrayList Usuario y no me la modifica en el ArrayList Equipo, como podré conseguir modificar también los datos en el ArrayList Equipo al mismo tiempo que modifico los datos de mi ArrayList Usuario? perdon si estoy redundando mucho.

Comment: Hola Fabix2019. Bienvenido. Te agradeceríamos que pusieras algo de código para poder ayudarte mejor. Gracias

Comment: intenta, busca, documentate.. I pica codigo! Si falla tu codigo, busca donde falla, comparte el codigo y te ayudaremos a resvoler el error que podamos detectar.

Comment: Hola Fabix2019, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son.  

mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No das muchos detalles pero me da lasensación de que intentas duplicar la información en el ArrayList Equipo. ¿Qué tal si simplemente mantienes una referencia al objeto Usuario?

```
Usuario usuario1 = new Usuario("user1", "Nombre1", "Apellido1", "correo1@email.com", "rol1");
listaUsuarios.add(usuario1);
Equipo equipo1 = new Equipo("Equipo1", 1, usuario1);
listaEquipos.add(equipo1);
```

si ahora modificaras la información del usuario:

```
usuario1.setNombre("NombreNuevo");
usuario1.setApellido("ApellidoNuevo");
```

...te aseguras de que la información del usuario se mantenga sincronizada entre las dos listas sin tener que preocuparte por actualizarla manualmente.

Comment: Excelente gracias, no creo que sea duplicar si no más bien sincronizar la información al mismo tiempo, por ejemplo si actualizo la información de un usuario necesito que se actualice en mi ArrayListEquipo al mismo tiempo, pero igual creo que es exactamente como me lo aclaraste, te lo agradezco mucho